# PHP & SQL Photo Gallery Placeholder Image

Tags: php, mysql

I have a function called RandomPic() it will display a Random Photo from the Database. Now i want a Placeholder Image for the Gallerys Categories that are empty. but my code doesnt work. it doesn't show the placeholder image....any ideas? here is the code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM wp_gallery WHERE catid = $id ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
if($result = $conn->query($sql)){

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {$imglos = '<img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.anyurl.com'.$row["filename"].'">';}

}

}
else{$imglos = 'PLACEHOLDERIMAGE GOES HERE';}
return $imglos;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slightly change your code structure:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM wp_gallery WHERE catid = $id ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
if($result = $conn->query($sql))
{
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
    {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        $imglos = '<img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.anyurl.com'.$row["filename"].'">';
    }    
    else
        $imglos = 'TEST';    

    return $imglos;
}
else
    return "database error!";
```

Some notes:

- The `mysqli_num_rows` never changes after executing a query: it returns the number of rows in the resultset. So it makes no sense to check for this within a `while`.
- There is no need for `while`, because your query can only return 0 or 1 results. If you do want to return multiple images you can append to `$imglos`:

  ```
  while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) )
       $imglos .= '<img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.anyurl.com'.$row["filename"].'">';
  ```